# rhandsontable: need to view table before using in calculations?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I have a Shiny app where the user uploads a bunch of input tables via CSV.  These tables are then make into rhandsontables which are used in subsequent calculations.  I am using rhandsontable to allow the user to modify the tables as necessary.

As it stands, my code looks roughly like this:

```
UI:

rHandsontableOutput("mytable_out")

server:

mytable <- reactive({*code to upload from CSV* })
output$mytable_out <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(mytable()) )


#Within an actionbutton observeEvent:
mytable_useforcalcs <-  hot_to_r(input$mytable_out ) 
#use mytable_useforcalcs in the subsequent calculations
```

This works well *except* for one issue.  In order to use *mytable_useforcalcs* in the subsequent calculations, I first have to actually click onto the tab that contains my RHOT `output$mytable_out`.  In the actual app, this can take a while as there are a bunch of tables, many of them quite large. I'd like to be able to just upload my CSV files and click the `actionButton` that starts the calculations.  Unfortunately, if I do that I get errors because my code cannot find `input$mytable_out` and thus cannot make `mytable_useforcalcs`.

Answer (score 0):

This works, put it in the actionbutton ObserveEvent:
`mytable_useforcalcs <- if(!is.null(input$mytable_out)){hot_to_r(input$mytable_out)} else { isolate( mytable()) }`